# How to upgrade PHP to 5.6.x or 7.0.x on CentOS 7.2?

Tags: centos, php, php-fpm, centos7

I'm on CentOs 7.2 with PHP 5.4.16.

I'd like to update to PHP 5.6.x or maybe even to PHP 7.0.x if it's safe to do.

What are the steps to safely switch to a newer PHP version?

These are PHP related installed packages:

```
php.x86_64                       5.4.16-36.el7_1                       @updates 
php-bcmath.x86_64                5.4.16-36.el7_1                       @updates 
php-cli.x86_64                   5.4.16-36.el7_1                       @updates 
php-common.x86_64                5.4.16-36.el7_1                       @updates 
php-fpm.x86_64                   5.4.16-36.el7_1                       @updates 
php-gd.x86_64                    5.4.16-36.el7_1                       @updates 
php-intl.x86_64                  5.4.16-36.el7_1                       @updates 
php-mbstring.x86_64              5.4.16-36.el7_1                       @updates 
php-mysql.x86_64                 5.4.16-36.el7_1                       @updates 
php-pdo.x86_64                   5.4.16-36.el7_1                       @updates 
php-pear.noarch                  1:1.9.4-21.el7                        @base    
php-process.x86_64               5.4.16-36.el7_1                       @updates 
php-xml.x86_64                   5.4.16-36.el7_1                       @updates
```

Comment: Does your repository have `php56-*` and `php70-*` packages?

Comment: Choose a repository with it, read any notes for that repo and then install. [Remi](http://rpms.famillecollet.com) is a common choice but there are others.

Comment: I am using the default repos and PHP 5.4.16 is the latest version. Is it safe to follow [these steps](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/install-epel-and-additional-repositories-on-centos-and-red-hat) to upgrade PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the [Remi repo](http://blog.remirepo.net/post/2015/12/18/PHP-version-7.0.1-en) has php7 for EL6 and EL7. If I were going to step outside the OS Vendors repos, Remi would be one I would trust.

Comment: Thank you! I think I'll try the steps mentioned [here](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/install-epel-and-additional-repositories-on-centos-and-red-hat).